# Django/DRF - REST API endpoint with query parameter that goes queries multiple endpoints

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, endpoint

Hey guys I'm having some trouble trying to architect how this endpoint would work. Currently I would like this endpoint `"/nba/players?date=01012016"` to work by going two different endpoints for results.

Currently my GameDates endpoint returns something similar to

```
{id: 1, home_team_id: 1, away_team_id: 2, date: "1/1/2016"},
{id: 4, home_team_id: 2, away_team_id: 3, date: "1/2/2016"}
```

I want to grab that GameDate_id or it's primary key (in this case id:1) which then gets passed on to a another PlayerStatistic endpoint which will return something like this -

```
{id: 1, game_id: 1, player_id: 1, team_id: 1, points: 20, assists: 10, rebounds: 2},
{id: 2, game_id: 1, player_id: 2, team_id: 1, points: 15, assists: 2, rebounds: 2},
{id: 3, game_id: 1, player_id: 3, team_id: 2, points: 10, assists: 2, rebounds: 20},
{id: 4, game_id: 1, player_id: 4, team_id: 2, points: 5, assists: 1, rebounds: 2}
```

My initial endpoint with the date query would return these four JSON since a player had a game on that date (game_id = 1) from the GameDate endpoint, then that game_id gets used to query
the PlayerStatistic endpoint and returns.

I know the right method of say overriding the get_queryset function something like -

```
 def get_queryset(self):
        date = self.request.query_params.get('date')
        queryset = self.queryset
        if date:
            # the rest here?
```

to grab the parameters but I'm not sure how to go from there.

edit - Added my models below -

```
class Player(models.Model):
    # class for Player model

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class GameDate(models.Model):
    # class for GameDate model

    home_team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_games',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    away_team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_games',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()


class PlayerStatistic(models.Model):
    # class for individual player statistics

    game_id = models.ForeignKey(GameDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_id = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    assists = models.IntegerField()
    rebounds = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: You're thinking the wrong way. You can't call an endpoint from another endpoint, at least there's no necessity for that. You just need to call your playerstats endpoint and filter the players queryset based on the date correctly. Show us your models for games and players (or player stats).

Comment: @dirkgroten I have updated my post with my models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `_id` from all your `ForeignKey` fields, it makes for very confusing code: If you have a `Player` instance, then `player.team_id` is a `Team` instance (not the id of the team) and `player.team_id_id` is the id. See how confusing?

So assuming you've removed all the `_id`, here's how to fetch all player stats for a particular date:

```
PlayerStatistics.objects.filter(game__date=date)
# or inside `get_queryset(self)`:
super().get_queryset().filter(game__date=date)
```

You can further order by game (if there's more than one game on the same date), then team and highest scores:

```
PlayerStatistics.objects.filter(game__date=date).order_by('game', 'team', '-points')
```

`date` needs to be a `datetime.date` object, so if your input is a string, then make sure you first convert it to a proper date object.

If you're actually listing `Player` instances for a specific date (and want to nest the related stats per player):

```
Player.objects.filter(
      Q(team__home_games__date=date) 
    | Q(team__away_games__date=date))\
              .prefetch_related('playerstatistics')
```

Here I've changed your `related_name` on the `home_team` and `away_team` fields, because they are used for the **reverse** relationship as you can see here (from team to game) so they should contain the word `games` not `team`.

If you only want players for which statistics have been recorded, then try this:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

player_stats = PlayerStatistics.objects.filter(game__date=date, player=OuterRef('pk'))
Player.objects.filter(
      Q(team__home_games__date=date) 
    | Q(team__away_games__date=date))\
        .annotate(has_stats=Exists(player_stats))
        .filter(has_stats=True)
        .prefetch_related('playerstatistics'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I see what you mean by removing the _id's. Anyways, each of these models have their own specific view (PlayerViewset, GameDateViewset, and PlayerStatisticViewset), if I'm providing query parameters like in /nba/players?date=01012016 don't I need that add to the Players view/viewset? Unless there's a way to route "players?date" to the PlayerStatistics viewset in urls.py? Sorry for the naive questions.

edit - Actually could I have something like "path('players/', 
         nv.PlayerStatisticDetailViewSet.as_view(),
         name='player-game-stats)"?

Comment: well it's a bit strange that you want the url /players returns the results from the PlayerViewset if there's no date but if there's a date as query parameter it returns an entirely different resource, namely the PlayerStatisticsViewset. It should return the same list, but filtered with the date, somehow. You might want to separate /players and /player-stats as different urls.

Comment: It's important when designing an API to carefully think about the various urls. A good REST API for a resource `game` is: GET /games/ returns the list of `Game`, filters can be added (/games/?date=xxx). POST /games/ creates a new game. GET /games/id fetches a specific game and POST /games/id updates an existing game. Delete is a bit tricky (should be DELETE /games/id but browser don't do DELETE) so I usually do POST /games/id/delete.

Comment: Ideally I would have done that but I'm doing this for an assessment and these are some of the requirements - 

- GET /nba/players
- Returns all player

- GET /nba/players?date=01012016 
- Returns all players who played (i.e. had player stats) on a specific date (date format: MMDDYYYY)

- GET /nba/players/1
- Returns the player object of the id specified

  - GET /nba/players/1/stats
  - Returns all player stats objects for the specified player

Comment: that actually looks fine to me, "returns all players who played on a specific date" would be `Player.objects.filter(Q(team__home_games__date=date) | Q(team__away_games__date=date))`

Comment: then in your serializer, if you want to add the stats, just nest the `PlayerStatistics` for the player. But it's all in the `PlayerViewSet`

Comment: So would it look something like this? 

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Serializer for Player objects

    stats = PlayerStatisticSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: yep, exactly. Refer to [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: I just find it strange that the list contains the stats, but the specific player doesn't unless you add /stats to the url. That makes it a bit complicated.

Comment: But in your viewset's `list()` or `retrieve()` method, you can check whether or not you need to nest the stats and pass an argument to the serializer, so in the serializer's `__init__()` method you could add/remove the nested serializer depending on the argument.

Comment: Yeah, I found it strange too as it would make more sense to have the query parameter on an endpoint/model that kinda contains the data. But I guess the assessment wants to see how you do more esoteric things I guess? If I were to do this on my own I would have no idea how to do this lol.

Comment: Also since I now have PlayerStatistics nested as a 'stats' variable in my Player Serializer, all the associated stats will be in the form of a list of objects/dictionaries correct? Will the "Player.objects.filter(
      Q(team__home_games__date=date) 
    | Q(team__away_games__date=date))\
              .prefetch_related('playerstatistics')" know to look into that specific nested list?

Comment: First question: yes. But second question doesn't make sense. The serializer takes the queryset (which contains all player stats due to the prefetch_related, this is just an optimisation, if it wasn't there the serializer would perform a separate query for each player) and creates the JSON. DRF serialisers are smart enough to look for reverse relationships when you nest another **model serialiser**.

Comment: This comment chain is kinda long winded but maybe one last question... This is more of a question so I can understand. We don't need to nest the GameDate serializer because we have access to the related_names that we supplied in the GameDate model correct? Is that how PlayerStaistic serializer being nested in the Player serializer gives us access to the date because of the game_id foreign key relation from PlayerStatistic model to the GameDate model?

Comment: No. The queryset is passed to the serializer. The serializer’s only job is to serialize: it takes the Queryset, evaluates it (makes the actual query to the db) and turns the result (a list of objects) into a list/dictionary that can be dumped as json. The players are fetched based on the date (the db query takes care of that), the serializer matches the nested player stats for each player based on the FK to player.

Comment: TL;DR serializers **format** the data the way you want. Querysets **select** which objects should be serialized.

Comment: Hey, very sorry to bother again but now I'm getting a "Cannot find 'playerstatistic' on Player object, 'playerstatistic' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()" error. I'm guessing the nested serializer isn't properly attaching itself? I tried doing something like 'player__playerstatistic' in prefetch but that didn't work either. Here is a pastebin of a bit of code I used - pastebin.com/fxzXuTTV.

edit - I seemed to have fixed it by using playerstatistic_set, but now it returns all of the players even though my PlayerStatistic table only has one row in it

Comment: That row being "{id: 1, game_id: 1, player_id: 1, team_id: 1, points: 20, assists: 10, rebounds: 2", so my initial query of /nba/players?date=01012016 should have only returned player_id 1's object instead of all the Player rows

Comment: Was assuming every player would have stats if they were in a game. In that case, the query is a bit more complex, i'll update my answer in a bit.